# Map javascript array to array of height gaps

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a decently tricky javascript data manipulation problem that I am struggling with. I have the following array of data:

```
var myArray = [8, 13, 11, 17, 5, 13, 13];
```

And I would like to map this array into an array of equal length, where each value in the new array *is equal to the difference between the array's previous value at that spot, and the next lowest value in the previous array*. This is wordy, but for example, I want the output to be:

```
var newArray = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0];
```

3 in the first element is (8 - 5), where 8 is the array's previous value in the first slot, and 5 is the next lowest value in the previous array. 
2 in the second element is (13 - 11), ... etc.

I'm not particularly caring how to handle ties (for example there are 2 values of 13 in the original array), so long as exactly one instance of 13 is replaced with (13 - next lowest value), and all other instances of 13 are replaced with zero (13 - 13 essentially).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code base already?

Comment: I've spent time pondering the Q, but no I do not have code attempting a solution. This has the feeling of a Q where, once I have an approach on how to calculate it, the code is written in <1 minute.

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: I'm actively working on it and will certainly post if i come up with a solution before an answer is posted

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar there will never be negative values in my dataset

Comment: So rule is replace all duplicates with zero? Not following loci there

Comment: replace all but one duplicate with 0. for one duplicate, replace with the same calculation used to replace other values

Comment: why is second item not 13-8 but 13-11? is it correct?

Comment: The closest number to 13, that is less than 13, in the original array, is 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a reduce() within map() and checking if number is first instance or not using indexOf()

```js
var arr = [8, 13, 11, 17, 5, 13, 13];

var res = arr.map((n, i) => {
  if (i !== arr.indexOf(n)) return 0;
  return n - arr.reduce((a, c) => c < n && c > a ? c : a, 0);
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))/// [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
```

Alternate  approach that creates descending sorted uniques array and then looks for number in next index within that array

```js
var arr = [8, 13, 11, 17, 5, 13, 13];
var sortedUniques  = [...new Set(arr)].sort((a,b) => b-a);

var res = arr.map((n, i) => {
  if (i !== arr.indexOf(n)) return 0;
  var sortedIdx = sortedUniques.indexOf(n);
  return n - ( sortedUniques[sortedIdx+1] || 0 );
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))/// [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
```

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar why not? That seems like only an opinion. Was easy enough for me to read while writing it

Comment: Code is very intuitive. I may do a challenge in codegolf with this question and take this answer as an example

Comment: @charlietfl yup its just my opinion. Not used to writing code like this. This makes sense to me though.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz think I have a more efficient idea. working on it

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz added what may be slightly more performant approach

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @charlietfl who helped me to understand the part about the duplicates :) In general i came up with an almost identical solution, save for using `Array.filter` and `Math.max` instead of minimizing that to a single `Array.reduce` statement.

```js
let myArray = [8, 13, 11, 17, 5, 13, 13],
    cmpArray = myArray.concat([0]);

console.log(
  myArray.map((value, index) => {
    if(index !== myArray.indexOf(value)) return 0;
    return value - Math.max(...cmpArray.filter(number => number < value));
  })
);
```

Comment: i see, i am having a hard time deciphering the requirements

Comment: if its a dup just return zero ... *"all other instances of 13 are replaced with zero"*

Comment: can i replace all 13 with 0, even if there would be 3 times 13 in it?

Comment: First one found is supposed to be evaluated. That's why I used indexOf() to check

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the next values in an array and all array in an object and pop the values until all values are taken.

```js
var array = [8, 13, 11, 17, 5, 13, 13],
    temp = array
        .slice()
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .reduce(
            (r, v, i, a) => ((r[v] = r[v] || []).push(v - (a[i + 1] || 0)), r),
            Object.create(null)
        ),
    result = array.map(v => temp[v].pop());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines is getting close for me.

```
let newArray = [];
myArray.forEach(function(d){
  let temp = myArray.filter(val => val < d)
  let maxRemVal = d3.max(temp)
  maxRemVal = isNaN(maxRemVal) ? 0 : maxRemVal;
  newArray.push(d - maxRemVal)
});
```